# Do Python 2 and 3 share the same set of magic methods?

Tags: python, magic-methods

Do Python 2 and 3 share all the same magic methods (with their names being exactly the same)?

If not, does anyone know of a handy comprehensive list of all the magic methods in Python 3?

Comment: Why? You either need them and research what you need or you do not need them and you are fine without them. `python magic methods` google -> 31.2 Million results. Why do they not help you?

Comment: Maybe you could compare [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: Off the top of my head, `__matmul__` was introduced in Python 3, and `__nonzero__` was dropped from Python 3 (replaced with `__bool__`?).

Answer (score 3):

[Magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-magic-method) are synonymous with what Python more formally calls [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-special-method). The special methods in Python 3 are documented under [3.3. Special method names -- Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), and those in Python 2 are documented under [3.4. Special method names -- Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames).

A quick search (via `grep -oh "__\w*__" | sort | uniq`) yields the following special names<sup>(1)</sup> for Python 3:

```
__abs__
__add__
__aenter__
__aexit__
__aiter__
__and__
__anext__
__annotations__
__await__
__bases__
__bool__
__bytes__
__call__
__ceil__
__class__
__classcell__
__class_getitem__
__closure__
__code__
__complex__
__contains__
__defaults__
__del__
__delattr__
__delete__
__delitem__
__dict__
__dir__
__divmod__
__doc__
__enter__
__eq__
__exit__
__file__
__float__
__floor__
__floordiv__
__format__
__func__
__future__
__ge__
__get__
__getattr__
__getattribute__
__getitem__
__globals__
__gt__
__hash__
__iadd__
__iand__
__ifloordiv__
__ilshift__
__imatmul__
__imod__
__import__ (2)
__imul__
__index__
__init__
__init_subclass__
__instancecheck__
__int__
__invert__
__ior__
__ipow__
__irshift__
__isub__
__iter__
__itruediv__
__ixor__
__kwdefaults__
__le__
__len__
__length_hint__
__lshift__
__lt__
__match_args__
__matmul__
__missing__
__mod__
__module__
__mro__
__mro_entries__
__mul__
__name__
__ne__
__neg__
__new__
__next__
__objclass__
__or__
__pos__
__pow__
__prepare__
__qualname__
__radd__
__rand__
__rdivmod__
__repr__
__reversed__
__rfloordiv__
__rlshift__
__rmatmul__
__rmod__
__rmul__
__ror__
__round__
__rpow__
__rrshift__
__rshift__
__rsub__
__rtruediv__
__rxor__
__self__
__set__
__setattr__
__setitem__
__set_name__
__slots__
__str__
__sub__
__subclasscheck__
__traceback__
__truediv__
__trunc__
__weakref__
__xor__
```

and these special names for Python 2:

```
__abs__
__add__
__and__
__bases__
__call__
__class__
__closure__
__cmp__
__code__
__coerce__
__complex__
__contains__
__defaults__
__del__
__delattr__
__delete__
__delitem__
__delslice__
__dict__
__div__
__divmod__
__doc__
__enter__
__eq__
__exit__
__file__
__float__
__floordiv__
__func__
__future__
__ge__
__get__
__getattr__
__getattribute__
__getitem__
__getslice__
__globals__
__gt__
__hash__
__hex__
__iadd__
__iand__
__idiv__
__ifloordiv__
__ilshift__
__imod__
__imul__
__index__
__init__
__instancecheck__
__int__
__invert__
__iop__
__ior__
__ipow__
__irshift__
__isub__
__iter__
__itruediv__
__ixor__
__le__
__len__
__long__
__lshift__
__lt__
__metaclass__
__missing__
__mod__
__module__
__mro__
__mul__
__name__
__ne__
__neg__
__new__
__nonzero__
__oct__
__op__
__or__
__pos__
__pow__
__radd__
__rand__
__rcmp__
__rdiv__
__rdivmod__
__repr__
__reversed__
__rfloordiv__
__rlshift__
__rmod__
__rmul__
__rop__
__ror__
__rpow__
__rrshift__
__rshift__
__rsub__
__rtruediv__
__rxor__
__self__
__set__
__setattr__
__setitem__
__setslice__
__slots__
__str__
__sub__
__subclasscheck__
__truediv__
__unicode__
__weakref__
__xor__
```

Comparing these lists, we get the following names which are mentioned in Python 3 data model (as of Python 3.10) but not in the Python 2 data model:

```
__aenter__
__aexit__
__aiter__
__anext__
__annotations__
__await__
__bool__
__bytes__
__ceil__
__classcell__
__class_getitem__
__dir__
__floor__
__format__
__imatmul__
__import__ (2)
__init_subclass__
__kwdefaults__
__length_hint__
__match_args_
__matmul__
__mro_entries__
__next__
__objclass__
__prepare__
__qualname__
__rmatmul__
__round__
__set_name__
__traceback__
__trunc__
```

and these names which are mentioned in the Python 2 data model but not in the Python 3 data model:

```
__cmp__
__coerce__
__delslice__
__div__
__getslice__
__hex__
__idiv__
__iop__
__long__
__metaclass__
__nonzero__
__oct__
__op__
__rcmp__
__rdiv__
__rop__
__setslice__
__unicode__
```

Do note that just because a name is mentioned in both the Python 2 and Python 3 data models doesn't necessarily mean that it has special meaning in both versions or that its meaning hasn't evolved. A more detailed reading of the documentation would be required to use this information in any meaningful way (static analysis, parsing, etc).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> These lists should not be taken to be exhaustive lists of all special identifiers in Python that follow the [reserved](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) `__<name>__` naming scheme. They are merely lists of identifiers of the `__<name>__` form that happen to appear somewhere in the Python data model documentation. This means that they should include all *special methods* and *special attributes* defined in Python, but they will not include special identifiers that come up in other contexts. For example, the special name [`__debug__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#debug__) is not included, since it is not referenced anywhere in the data model documentation.

<sup>(2)</sup> The name `__import__` is not a special method or special attribute in the Python data model, but rather is just a uniquely named [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-funcs). It's also present in both Python 2 and Python 3, despite what the lists above may suggest. This erratum is left intact to emphasize that fact that theses lists are merely lists of all identifiers of the  form `__<name>__` found in the Python data model documentation, and have not (yet) been scrutinized to ensure that they include only special methods and special attributes.

Comment: Note that as you made just the grep, some of the names might not correspond to magic methods, but be other names with the same pattern. From the listings, I know that is the case for `__import__` (and maybe it is the only case - the others should either be methods or attributes)